# numpy reshape() when last shape int is = 1

Tags: python, numpy

It appears that a trailing `1` in the shape parameter simple transposes the base ndarray, is that the correct way to think about it?

```
    In [22]: np.ones((3, 2))
    Out[22]: 
    array([[ 1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.]])

    In [23]: np.ones((3, 2, 1))
    Out[23]: 
    array([[[ 1.],
            [ 1.]],

           [[ 1.],
            [ 1.]],

           [[ 1.],
            [ 1.]]])
```

I'm wondering if there are performance reasons to specify the trailing `1` as well.

Comment: The trailing one adds another axis at the end.  Transposing is essentially reversing the order of the axes, which is something quite different.

Comment: so how can I think about going from the shape parameter handed to `np.ones()` -> the dimensions on the final matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 Numpy arrays are different in structure while the number of values stay the same.  Example: If you were thinking about a spreadsheet `np.ones((3, 2))` would have 2 columns of data and 3 rows while `np.ones((3, 2, 1))` would have only 1 column and 2 rows over 3 sheets.

You can go from one to the other using `reshape()` so just think about the block of data in the most helpful configuration knowing you can change it later.
examples `np.ones((3,2)).reshape(1,2,1,3)` (this is now 4 dimensions with the same number of values)

As for performance there isn't any difference.
It's still a big block of the same types of data referenced efficiently.